# Can Force.com - App Subscription License users not run Flows?

Tags: visual-workflow, permissions, force.com

I have set up a record change launched flow that posts to a slack channel when a record meets a certain condition. I've set up the Force.com - App Subscription users with a permission set that includes "Run Flow" and even "Manage Flow" and given them all access to the slack objects, but the flow never fires for the force.com users. For full license users, the flow and slack post work without issue.

Are force.com users really not allowed to run flows? Or is it something with the slack integration?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the non full license users needed the "Slack Standard User" permission set assigned